# How to get notified by Microsoft Exchange Server in a C# code when a new mail is reveived?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exchange-server

I need help in implementing a program using C# that gets notified by Exchange Server every time a new message is received by a certain mailbox , the C# program needs to collect some information from the mail received and save those infos in a SQL-Server Database .Please provide me any infos , or links/ code sample to implement this , any advices on how to achieve this would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting notifications, you can subscribe to the mailbox folders. That way you can get notification every time you receive an email and there are various event types to subscribe to.

This is the link you can follow for the notification purpose:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792(v=exchg.150).aspx

Mostly its better to get the notifications from the resources as the logged in user has permissions to the resources. You have to log in as the same user if you want the access to that specific mailbox folder.

I believe the EventType.Created event will give you access to the notification where any incoming message will push out the notification.